# How to add a click event on a button created with javascript in a Ol3 popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers-3

I am working on a web mapping app with Openlayers 3, I display features (points) on the map and when I click on them I display a popup where I added a button. Here is the popup and the button code first :

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
popup.hide();
popup.setOffset([0, 0]);

 // Attempt to find a feature in one of the visible vector layers
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
return feature;
});
if (feature) {
    var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var props = feature.getProperties();
    var info =  "<input type='button' id='popupButton' value='Get here ?' />" ;
    // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
    popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
    popup.show(coord, info);
    }   
});
```

After that I saw some similar questions in stackoverflow and I tried this code to launch a function when the event is fired:

```
$(document).on("click", "#popupButton", function(){
      alert(nearest_feature(my_position)); 
});
```

the problem is that the event isn't fired, I tried replacing document with '#map' ( which is the div where the map is shown) but still nothing.

How can I trigger the event for that button inside the popup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code that @Jesper Højer and @Marius gave in their answers it didn't work at first so I added it in the:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
---------
$("#popupButton").on("click", function(){
      alert(nearest_feature(my_position)); 
});
}
```

and it worked now the event is triggered

Comment: But now you are setting the eventlistener every time you click on map??

Comment: Could you say $(document).ready(function() {
$("#popupButton").on("click", function(){
      alert(nearest_feature(my_position)); 
});
Outside of the map.on.

Comment: since the popup appears only when I click on a feature on the map and then creates the #popupButton. I guess it should be fine now, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Ahh, I understand what you are attempting to do now :) You could also set it like this then map.on('click', '#popupButton', function() {alert(nearest_feature(my_position)); });

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that too, I even delegated the event to many other static elements of the html page but still nothing. surprisingly when I included the event insid the singleclick event of the map it worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing it, the way I think you are using it, and it worked?

```
<div id='container'>
<button id="AddDynamicBtn">
Add Dynamic Btn
</button>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').on('click','#DynamicBtn', function() {
    alert('TEST');
  });
    $('#AddDynamicBtn').on('click',function() {
        $('#container').append('<button id="DynamicBtn">Dynamic Btn</button>');
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d9eubeeu/

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but the event still wasn't triggered

Comment: I forgot to mention that the popup by itself isn't an html element, I declared it inside the javascript file as an  ol.Overlay.Popup(); from Openlayers 3.
I don't see how I can append the button to it this way

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that event bubbling is taking place? There is already a listener on the map. Potentially there might also be one on the popup. If you pass in the event as a parameter to your function you could use:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```